# Ubuntu 20 dual boot installation Error : No firmware reserved region can cover this

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, bios, uefi

I was trying to install ubuntu-20.02 (using Pendrive) dual boot in **HP-notebook-15-ac101tu** with **windows 10**, a little old machine. At first, I didn't know to look for **BIOS/UEFI**, so tried bios installation which didn't work, then erased the pen drive, volume and tried the UEFI installation by Rufus software, I have put GPT and loaded iso image.

Installation is happening, with an error flashing (couldn't write the whole error, let me know if it is important)

```
DMRR :: [Firmware Bug] : No firmaware reserved region can cover this
RMRR [0x00000000009d000000-000000000fffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes
0.727643] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol ...
0.727643] Error: Aborting method \T2.t200._TMP due to previous error ...
0.727643] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol ...
0.727643] Error: Aborting method \T2.t200._TMP due to previous error ...
0.727643] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol ...
0.727643] Error: Aborting method \T2.t200._TMP due to previous error ...
0.727643] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol ...
0.727643] Error: Aborting method \T2.t200._TMP due to previous error ...
```

I ignored it, but ubuntu is not showing up in the dual boot. If I plugin pen drive again, it goes to installation. I did a BIOS update and tried to install it, it shows the same error and then no option in dual boot. I don't understand the error in its nature itself, If some can explain, please help me out.

What all I used: Rufus, SD card formater, Easy BCD *(this software is not letting me add linux option)*

Comment: First of all, do not use EasyBCD for UEFI. The equivalent tool is EasyUEFI but you shouldn't need it anyway. Before any other troubleshooting please check UEFI settings > Boot and change "Windows bootloader manager" to Ubuntu. In some HP laptops this doesn't work either as the firmware keeps reverting the boot order back to Windows. If that's the case better to run Ubuntu from the ESC initial menu.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!! I understood that Easy BDC wont work but in one of the videos , it got enabled also after installation. But changing the boot loader option in uefi settings did the magic !! Everywhere answers were about secureboot/legacy support changes but all that is totally unecessary

Comment: @ChanganAuto pleae write an answer officially so il approve it or you want me to write it down, i also understood that disabling installing update while ubuntu installation is the culprit, in the manual update log later... i saw "change bootloader to ubuntu", so actually ubuntu took care of uefi issue with its 20.00 release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before any other troubleshooting please check UEFI settings > Boot and change "Windows bootloader manager" to Ubuntu.

In some HP laptops this doesn't work either as the firmware keeps reverting the boot order back to Windows. If that's the case better to run Ubuntu from the ESC initial menu.

As a side note, do not use EasyBCD for UEFI, it works only for BIOS/Legacy installations. The equivalent tool for UEFI is EasyUEFI but you shouldn't need it anyway.

Comment: Is this instruction for before installing Ubuntu? If so where does Ubuntu boot loader come from?

Comment: @RichardTingle This are instruction for *after* installing Ubuntu and the installation couldn't interact properly with UEFI in order to change the boot order to Ubuntu. This are instructions (+ a remark) for changing the boot order "manually". If you have read the question & comments below the question you wouldn't need to ask.